# I have a problem with a docker npm install when create a container

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-install

Hello people i tried to run docker-composer to install a mern stack, but when the script run npm install -g nodemon i have these errors:

note i dont have any proxy confi in mi deepin system

```
mongodb uses an image, skipping
Building backend
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10.15.3
 ---> 5a401340b79f
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9acebabc62b0
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ceb2f805862d
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install -g npm@latest
 ---> Running in 9f30ffd8e0e4
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Can you at least ping the outside world from inside the container?

Comment: You could try to set DNS for your docker so that inside Docker container you can able to call request to outside domains

Comment: how to set dns inside of docker container ?

Comment: Try to use EXPOSE: `EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]` . Go here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: i run script with ping www.google .. and i have these error now: Step 4/7 : RUN ping www.google.com
 ---> Running in 341923cfd1b0
ping: socket: Permission denied

Comment: Well, then you can set `USER root` in your dockerfile prior to the ping call, and see what happens.

Comment: I set USER root and i have a same problem, i read a posible deepin bug problem, https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/413

Comment: are you behind proxy?

Comment: i don have proxy in my network

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem remove apparmor,and i remember, i have a deepin 15.11 verion based on stable debian distro